# Spring Security Config: AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to this project and I try to run this in my local machine and got this error on the ubuntu 16.04LTS java api Spring security error. It seems that it doesn't what is wrong.

My Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("production")
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserAuthorizationService userAuthorizationService;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private ConfigurationParamsService configurationParamsService;

@Autowired
private AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler;

@Autowired
private AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/internal/v1/user/signup",
            "/api/internal/v1/user/activate",
            "/api/internal/v1/user/changePassword",
            "/api/internal/v1/user/password/reset",
            "/api/internal/v1/user/verifyPassword",
            "/api/internal/v1/accounts/activate",
            "/api/internal/v1/user/resend",
            "/api/internal/v1/user/quick_signup");
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.antMatcher("/api/internal/v1/user/login").csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/internal/v1/user/login").permitAll();

    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint()).accessDeniedHandler(oauthAccessDeniedHandler).and().antMatcher("/api/v3/oauth2/auth**").csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager).requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v3/oauth2/auth")).authenticated();

    http.rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
            .tokenValiditySeconds(Integer.parseInt(configurationParamsService.getRememberMeTokenValiditySeconds()));

}

@Bean
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public CustomEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
    return new CustomEntryPoint();
}

@Bean
public RememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(configurationParamsService.getRememberMeKey(), userAuthorizationService,
            tokenRepository());
    rememberMeServices.setAlwaysRemember(true);
    rememberMeServices.setCookieName(configurationParamsService.getRememberMeCookieName());
    rememberMeServices.setTokenValiditySeconds(Integer.parseInt(configurationParamsService.getRememberMeTokenValiditySeconds()));
    return rememberMeServices;
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    super.authenticationManagerBean();
    List<AuthenticationProvider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    providers.add(rememberMeAuthenticationProvider());

    return new ProviderManager(providers);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userAuthorizationService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(rememberMeAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository() {
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return tokenRepository;
}

@Bean
public RememberMeAuthenticationFilter rememberMeFilter() throws Exception {
    RememberMeAuthenticationFilter rememberMeFilter = new RememberMeAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean(), rememberMeServices());

    return rememberMeFilter;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new RememberMeAuthenticationProvider(configurationParamsService.getRememberMeKey());
}
}
```

My Gradle Build

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.4.0.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.1.RELEASE")
}
 }


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: "jacoco"

apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.trackimo.server'
version = '0.0.0.1'

// Uses JDK 8
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

// 1. Get dependencies from Maven local repository
// 2. Get dependencies from Maven central repository
repositories {
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
maven {
    url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot'
}
}
ext {

logbackVersion = '1.1.3'
jsonDocVersion = '1.1.13'
hibernateVersion = '4.3.11.Final'
servletVersion = '3.1.0'
mandrillVersion = '0.0.5'
jodaTimeVersion = '2.8'
mokitoVersion = '1.9.5'
jsonPathVersion = '2.1.0'
hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
junitVersion = '4.11'
springOAuth2Version = '2.0.8.RELEASE'
dbUnitVersion = '2.5.1'
springtestdbunitVersion = '1.2.1'
springRedisDataVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
redisClientVersion = '2.7.3'
quartzVersion = '2.2.1'
springContextVersion = '4.2.3.RELEASE'
commonsClientVersion = '3.1'
commonsUploadVersion = '1.3.1'
commonsIoVersion = '2.4'
kmlVersion = '2.2.1'
csvVersion = '1.2'
mailVersion = '1.4.7'
commonsLang3Version = '3.4'
cronparserVersion = '2.8'
brainTreePaymentsVersion = '2.52.0'
apachePioVersion = '3.13'
luceneVersion = '4.10.4'
ehcacheVersion = '2.6.11'
commonsValidator = '1.4.1'
airbrakeVersion = '2.2.8'
airbrakeLogbackVersion = '1.0.1'
}
configurations {
providedRuntime
}


dependencies {

// Amazon sqs dependency
compile "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:1.10.27"

//spring configuration
compile "org.springframework:spring-context:${springContextVersion}"
compile "org.springframework:spring-context-         support:${springContextVersion}"

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
//compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
compile('org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:2.2.0')
compile('com.spatial4j:spatial4j:0.4.1')
compile "com.vividsolutions:jts:1.13"

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-validator')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
runtime('com.h2database:h2')
//Social Dependencies
compile('org.springframework.social:spring-social-config')
compile('org.springframework.social:spring-social-core')
compile('org.springframework.social:spring-social-security')
compile('org.springframework.social:spring-social-web')
compile('org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:2.0.3.RELEASE')
compile('org.springframework.social:spring-social-google:1.0.0.RELEASE')
compile('org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:1.1.0.RELEASE')
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6')

compile "redis.clients:jedis:${redisClientVersion}"
compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:${springRedisDataVersion}"

//spring security
compile "org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:${springOAuth2Version}"

compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'

compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:${hibernateVersion}"
compile "net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:${ehcacheVersion}"

compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${logbackVersion}"


compile "commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:${commonsClientVersion}"
compile "commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:${commonsUploadVersion}"
compile "commons-io:commons-io:${commonsIoVersion}"
compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:${commonsLang3Version}"
compile "commons-validator:commons-validator:${commonsValidator}"

compile "com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung:lutung:${mandrillVersion}"

compile "org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:${quartzVersion}"
compile "org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-jobs:${quartzVersion}"

compile "javax.mail:mail:${mailVersion}"

compile "org.apache.commons:commons-csv:${csvVersion}"

compile "joda-time:joda-time:${jodaTimeVersion}"

//jsondoc configuration
compile "org.jsondoc:jsondoc-core:${jsonDocVersion}",
        "org.jsondoc:jsondoc-springmvc:${jsonDocVersion}"

compile "org.dbunit:dbunit:${dbUnitVersion}"
compile "com.github.springtestdbunit:spring-test-dbunit:${springtestdbunitVersion}"


compile "de.micromata.jak:JavaAPIforKml:${kmlVersion}"

compile "com.braintreepayments.gateway:braintree-java:${brainTreePaymentsVersion}"
compile "com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:3.4.5"

compile "org.apache.poi:poi:${apachePioVersion}"

compile 'com.paypal.sdk:adaptivepaymentssdk:2.8.117'

compile 'com.paypal.sdk:merchantsdk:2.14.117'

compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-core:1.7.0'

compile 'com.paypal.sdk:rest-api-sdk:1.4.1'

compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6'
compile 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.5.1'
runtime "io.airbrake:airbrake-java:${airbrakeVersion}"
compile "net.anthavio:airbrake-logback:${airbrakeLogbackVersion}"




testCompile("junit:junit:${junitVersion}") {
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:${jsonPathVersion}"
    "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:${jsonPathVersion}"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:${hamcrestVersion}"
    exclude(module: 'hamcrest-core')
}

testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.6.4"

 // testCompile('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4')
 // testCompile('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4' )

}


eclipse {
classpath {
    containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
    containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
}
}

jar { baseName = "trackimo" }

task coverageReport(type: JacocoReport) {

executionData = files("$buildDir/covarageTest/jacocoTest.exec")
classDirectories = files("$buildDir/classes");
sourceDirectories = files("src");

reports {
    xml.enabled false
    csv.enabled false
    html.destination "$buildDir/reports/covarageTest/jacocoHtml"
}

}

test {
jacoco {
    append = true
    destinationFile = file("$buildDir/covarageTest/jacocoTest.exec")
    classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/covarageTest/classpathdumps")

}
finalizedBy tasks.coverageReport
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '2.14' }
```

When I run the following code it cause an error below

Error Logs:

```
.19:42:21.368 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application    startup failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error     creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path    resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecur     ityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method   failed; nested exception is   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to    instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is     org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateU singFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans- 4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at com.trackimo.server.TrackimoServerApplication.main(TrackimoServerApplication.java:15) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:    Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method   'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This   object has already been built
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:44) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:105) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9a87c1cf.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$3(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9a87c1cf$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5dcb6e03.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at    org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecuri tyConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9a87c1cf.springSecurityFilterChain (<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorIm pl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.inst antiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-     4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted
:run FAILED
```

Comment: Hi this is close. answer The config is being duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

The following duplicate configuration was causing this issue:

```
http.antMatcher("/api/internal/v1/user/login").csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/internal/v1/user/login").permitAll();
```